# AlarmManager with a pendingIntent: set time is not registering properly

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-calendar

I am trying to use an alarmManager and a pendingIntent to allow my users to set a time at which a certain event will happen in my application. However, the BroadcastReceiver is initiating at the conclusion of the onClick event rather than at the intended time that I've just set. This has to be simple, but I'm not seeing it. Code is below.TIA.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
AlarmManager alarmManager;
TextView tvHours, tvMins;
int iHours = 23;
int iMins = 15;
int iSecs = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initiateBroadcastReceiver();
    findViewById(R.id.the_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    tvHours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Hours);
    String szHours = Integer.toString(iHours);
    tvHours.setText(szHours);

    tvMins = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Mins);
    String szMins = Integer.toString(iMins);
    tvMins.setText(szMins);
}

private void initiateBroadcastReceiver() {
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is the alarm event!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("pending event"));
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("pending event"), 0 );
    //PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, activate, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String szHours=tvHours.getText().toString();
    int iHourTemp = Integer.parseInt(szHours);
    if (iHourTemp < 24){
        iHours = iHourTemp;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter an hour value between 0 and 23.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    String szMins=tvMins.getText().toString();
    int iMinTemp = Integer.parseInt(szMins);
    if (iMinTemp < 60){
        iMins = iMinTemp;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter an minute value between 0 and 60.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, iHours);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, iMins);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, iSecs);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Event is now set for " +iHours+":"+iMins, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```

Comment: If the alarm fires immediately, then you've given a date/time in the past. You need to account for the possibility that the selected time has passed already today.

Answer (score 0):

You must be give receiver permission and service permission in android manifest file . you follow this step for Alarm manager.

Step1:You make AlarmReceiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String notification_msg = extras.getString("bookName");
    service1.putExtra("bookName",notification_msg);
    context.startService(service1);

}
}
```

Step2:You make new class of service,Its name AlarmService

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;


public AlarmService() {
    super("AlarmService");
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // don't notify if they've played in last 24 hr
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("", "test");
    mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String notification_msg = extras.getString("bookName");

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo_home)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.logo_home))
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(notification_msg);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());


}
}
```

Step3 where you want to set call alarm, do this code

```
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, lDay);
            calendar.set(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hours[0]));
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(hours[1]));
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            Date date = calendar.getTime();
            System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
            long sdl = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            alarmIntent.setData(Uri.parse("custom://" + Your Passing data));
                            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, index, alarmIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, sdl, pendingIntent);
            index++;
```

Step4 : give permission in manifest file like this

```
 <receiver android:name="com.sk.yman.utils.AlarmReceiver"  android:enabled="true"/>
    <service android:name="com.sk.yman.utils.AlarmService" />
```

for more help you follow this example

http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android